# How can I separate text with a delimiter when there is multiple lines?

Tags: bash

If I have a file such as this:

```
SomeText1#SomeText2
SomeText1-2#SomeText2-2
```

How can I separate each side with the delimiter "#" with multiple lines in a regular Linux shell?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "Separate" What would your output look like?

Comment: The sides *are* already separated with a delimiter, aren't they? If you just want to know how to do a read while splitting on an arbitrarily-chosen delimiter, that's covered in [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) -- see the example in there showing reading a file where fields are separated by `:`s.

Comment: try `tr '#' '\n' <file`

Comment: Huh. I can't say that that *isn't* what the OP wants, but I also can't say that it is either; there's just not enough in the question to go on.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert two column format to single column you can

```
$ awk -F# '{a[NR]=$2; print $1} END{for(k=1; k<=NR; k++) print a[k]}' file
SomeText1
SomeText1-2
SomeText2
SomeText2-2
```

or with `tr/pr`

```
$ tr '#' '\n' < file | pr -2ts'#' | tr '#' '\n'
SomeText1
SomeText1-2
SomeText2
SomeText2-2
```